# Java 2d array is printing what I assume is crap in memory instead of element

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm building a 2d array filled with 1's. 
when the array is initialized everything seems fine. I am attempting to print it to the console but as I iterate through the nested for loop to go through each element and I get 33 printed instead of 1. I've been running this through the debugger trying to figure it out but I'm stumped. In the debugger all the array elements are filled with 1's but it keeps printing 33.

```
        int NUMBER_OF_ROWS = 5;
    int NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 5;

    int[][] matrix = new int[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];



    int row=0;
    int col=0;

    // The column gets filled first in the nested loop, then the row gets
    // incremented. Then the next column gets filled.
    // After intializing all rows and columns are filled with 0
    for (row = 0; row < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; row++) {
        col = 0;
        for (col = 0; col < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; col++)
            matrix[row][col] = 1;
    }

    for (row = 0; row < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; row++) {
        System.out.println(' ');
        for (col =0; col < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; col++)
            System.out.print(matrix[row][col] + ' ');
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not *crap*. There is a problem with your code.

```
System.out.print(matrix[row][col] + ' ');
                          1       + 32 = 33  (Space is 32 in ASCII.)
```

Use:

```
System.out.print(matrix[row][col] + " "); //Convert to String and appends space.
```